# swift - MacOs application - add to finder contextual menu?

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, cocoa

Before all, I'm very new in swift cocoa application.

I'm developing an MacOS application for my company, the goal of this is to open a file ("right-click -> open with my app") to process it.

But after couples of search, I'm not enable to find a way to do it.
(I probably didn't search the good terms, but like I said I'm very new to this)

(I've done a similar things to windows, using the registers)

Somebody has an idea? link, documentation ?

Thanks !

Comment: I suggest reading Apple's documentation on [Launch Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCIntro/LSCIntro.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at Document based applications. It is a huge topic: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011179-CH1-SW1

As soon you register for types of documents you app can open, this feature will work the same way as in Windows. I.e. if you register custom extension, you app will onep this file by default. If you specify lets say you app can open pictures, it will show up in "open with" right click popup menu.

Pay attention to document types registration. Here is an example from one of the books (Learning Swift 2016):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [finder extensions](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/extensions/finder-sync-extensions/) to do this. If you need more flexibility, you can use notifications to communicate with the main app and change right click menu items dynamically. [Here](https://samiyuru.com/project/macOS-finder-right-click-menu) is an app that uses the approach to add custom right click menu items. The page has a link to the source. [finder extensions](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/extensions/finder-sync-extensions/) also have helpful examples.